# JAVASCRIPT: Console.log() does not print the value of arrays (with objects) correctly. Instead, it prints a summary

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, console.log

I have this simple javascript app.

```
let array = [{ fruit: "banana" }];
console.log(array);
array.push({ fruit: "apple" });
console.log(array);
```

I expect the first console.log() to print an array with one object. I also expect the second console.log() to print an array with two objects. And this is what gets printed in CHROME console.

```
[{…}]
(2)[{…}, {…}]
```

So everything seems to be all right. The first array seems to contain one object and the second array seems to contain two objects. But when I inspect the array in the console, this what I see.

```
[{…}]
  0: {fruit: 'banana'}
  1: {fruit: 'apple'}
  length: 2
  [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

(2)[{…}, {…}]
   0: {fruit: 'banana'}
   1: {fruit: 'apple'}
   length: 2
   [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

This is a very unexpected behavior, because the first object seems to contain two objects.

CHATGPT explained that this is a standard behavior. In addition to that, it admits that "console displaying summaries instead of the full content  can indeed be confusing at times"

The problem is that it makes debugging more difficult. It is not so easy to keep track of the values in my app. To see the content of the arrays, CHATGPT suggests to use JSON.stringify() method. Like this.

```
let array = [{ fruit: "banana" }];
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
array.push({ fruit: "apple" });
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

And it works, it gives me this result in the console.

```
[{"fruit":"banana"}]
[{"fruit":"banana"},{"fruit":"apple"}]
```

The problem with this method is that it works quite well with arrays that contain just a few simple objects. But it may be really difficult to read if there are many complex objects in the array.

So my question is. Apart from using the JSON.stringify() method, is there any other technique to make the arrays more readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console keeps references to objects you log into it (not copies). So when you expand an object in the console the current state of the object is displayed. Since you pushed a new element into the array before you expand the array you will have this new element added to the expanded array.

To change that you should log your object fully as text or make a copy of an object/array.

There are several methods to freeze the objects in the console.

One way would be to create a deep copy with `structuredClone()` to make a "current snapshot" of an object (you can create a deep copy also with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`).

That gives you exact the console's UX as with an original object (in our case an array):

```js
let array = [{ fruit: "banana" }];
console.log(structuredClone(array));
array.push({ fruit: "apple" });
console.log(structuredClone(array));
```

A shallow copy (shorter syntax) could be done with `arr.slice()` or spread `[...arr]`:

```js
let array = [{ fruit: "banana" }];
console.log(array.slice());
array.push({ fruit: "apple" });
console.log(array.slice());
```

You could use `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)` (where `4` means number of spaces to indent the JSON) to log in a readable form similar to the console expanded version:

```js
let array = [{ fruit: "banana" }];
console.log(JSON.stringify(array, null, 4));
array.push({ fruit: "apple" });
console.log(JSON.stringify(array, null, 4));
```

Also note that `console.log` takes multiple arguments so you could output arrays with the spread syntax too, thus at least displaying different item count:

```js
let array = [{ fruit: "banana" }];
console.log(...array);
array.push({ fruit: "apple" });
console.log(...array);
```

A combination of the both methods is possible, here we want a compact format and use `Array::map()` to stringify array items in a compact JSON form:

```js
let array = [{ fruit: "banana" }];
console.log(...array.map(JSON.stringify));
array.push({ fruit: "apple" });
console.log(...array.map(JSON.stringify));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `JSON.stringify()` as you said and `Object.map()` to specify the behaviour of each attribute with `console.table()`

```
let products = [
  { id: 1, name: "Laptop", price: 1000, specs: { CPU: "i7", RAM: "16GB", SSD: "512GB" } },
  { id: 2, name: "Smartphone", price: 800, specs: { CPU: "Snapdragon 888", RAM: "8GB", Storage: "128GB" } }
];

let displayProducts = products.map(product => {
  return {
    ...product,
    specs: JSON.stringify(product.specs)
  };
});

console.table(displayProducts); 
// Or console.log(displayProducts);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll elaborate on what ChatGPT meant by "expected behavior" a little more here.

An important concept in computer science and programming is referred to as "pass by reference" or "pass by value", pass by reference is usually how we prefer our logic to sit, but not when we are dubugging.

As Alexander pointed out, Chrome is passing the array by reference to the console, at the end of execution, the array has two elements in it, and there is no array which has one element in it any more.