What does a top-level async function return in JavaScript?
If I call an async function that doesn’t explicitly return anything from the await, will it return a resolved Promise? Or Void? Something else?
For example an IIFE like this, or this but it being called in the global scope by sync code:
(async myFunc() {
   const list = await someFunc();
   const anotherList = someOtherFunc(list);
   console.log(anotherList);
})();

I have it in my head that all async functions return a Promise.

what happens if you try it?

I’m on my phone  and yes I wrote out the above function by hand lol

When you call a function it will return what you return in code.  In your case, undefined

@ITgoldman async functions always return a promise.

Yes, then you can await for it to resolve and get the value that was return-ed.

I think you might be talking about what’s returned in the PromiseResult? If the code in the function doesn’t return anything it’ll be undefined, otherwise the result will be the awaited result

"I have it in my head that all async functions return a Promise." - yes it does. Why do you doubt it? What do you think is different for a "top-level call" or "IIFE"?

I more wanted to know what the state of that Promise would look like. I believe that’s answered from other comments, as the Promise will resolve immediately with undefined result

If code inside the async IIFE is sync and no promise returned than it returns a resolved fullfilled  promise. If it contains await or returns a promise it returns a pending promise:


let promise = (async () => {

})();

console.log(promise.toString());

promise = (async () => {
   const list = await 1;
})();

console.log(promise.toString());





Why is it PromiseState: “fulfilled” and  in your second example? Is this weird because the await is acting like sync code by returning 1 immediately? Also I notice it doesn’t have a PromiseResult which I suppose I’d expect since the code in the Async function never sets the result

If it were to return list, the PromiseResult would be set to it, correct?

@MattStyles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76939148/javascript-console-log-does-not-print-the-value-of-arrays-with-objects-corr/76939242

Thanks, my guess for why it looks like that then is that to the console it’s printed as in a pending state but when you expanded it, the Promise referenced is now fulfilled some ms after console logging it

@MattStyles exactly

Asynchronous functions are just a wrapper around the Promise object. Normally, one creates a promise and passes in a callback function. When ready, the programmer calls the then method, et cetera. When using the async keyword, it simply abstracts that system. Therefore, it will always return a promise, even if you return something else, because it isn't actually returning what you return.


console.log((async () => {
    const list = await someFunc();
    const anotherList = someOtherFunc(list);
    console.log(anotherList);
})().toString());

console.log((async () => {
    const list = await someFunc();
    const anotherList = someOtherFunc(list);
    console.log(anotherList);
    return "foo";
})().toString());



